# How should I use OpenCV 3.1 ORB in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, orb

I'm new to CV,I have a lot of images and I want to compare one images with the others in my images dataset.So I decide to index all the images,after I do some search and know ORG,SIFT,SURF is I was looking for.But I don't know how to use the keypoint and descriptor,below is my code:

```
import cv2

nfeatures = 1
cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)
img = cv2.imread('images/forest-copyright.jpg', 0)
img2 = cv2.imread('images/forest-high.jpg', 0)

def kpdes(img):
    orb = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=nfeatures)
    kp = orb.detect(img, None)
    kp,des = orb.compute(img, kp)
    print(kp,des)

kpdes(img)
kpdes(img2)
```

Some parts of output:

> [KeyPoint 0000000002A2EF00]
>   [[252  48 188 124  41 124  81 184 161 
>   63 167  25  87  63  74  91 192 213   237   0  60  79 243   0 219 235
>   112  93 224 225  78  67]]

How should I use the descriptor like “[[252  48 188 124  41 124  81 184 161  63 167  25  87  63  74  91 192 213
  237   0  60  79 243   0 219 235 112  93 224 225  78  67]]”,what dose it mean?
How can I store them in Elasticsearch and query them?
I found the descriptor would be changed if I increase nfeatures.
Yes,there are so many questions for me,waiting for helper!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the implementation for ORB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQrES.png)

You use the keypoints and descriptors to match two images together for example. This can be done by finding the matches between them via: cv2.findHomography

Note if you are trying to stitch images you should ensure they are good matches by following lowe's ratio.

You can also use them to determine if an image is inside another such as is a pillow in one picture on a bed in another picture. Here is a link to a opencv python tutorial to do so: [Feature Matching](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html#py-feature-homography)